# How to Backspace New Line Characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, newlines, backspace

I have a file with the following format

```
dhdh
|jgfgf
hhgfh
```

I want to find the `|` (pipe) symbol in a new line and replace it with backspace

For finding this, my regex is as below

```
^[|]{1}[a-zA-Z]
```

It is working perfectly, but I am unable to replace it with backspace in end of previous line as below.

```
dhdh|jgfgf
hhgfh
```

And the second case for text only

```
^[a-zA-Z]
```

For this the desired result is

```
dhdh|jgfgfhhgfh
```

Please suggest me how can it be done?

Comment: And For Second Scenario?

Comment: not sure about the second scenario, could you give an example (before and after with the desired result)?

Comment: Same Example As For PIpe Symbol, the difference is it Don't have prefix PIPE(|) symbol in new line

Comment: please add a **specific** example into your question (before and the desired after) **not** just an explanation about it and **not** a general one with `^[a-zA-Z]` otherwise I'm not sure if I understand it correctly

Comment: Let Suppose I Have a Block with `jgfgfNEW_LINEhhgfh`, I Have to Replace it with `jgfgfSPACE_WITHOUT_NEWLINEhhgfh` EX:  `jgfgf hhgfh` like this

Comment: difficult to to say if I understand correctly through the comments (that's why you should add it to your question), but if I do you just need to replace the line break characters with a space. But you will need something to evaluate when **not** to replace the line break, other wise you will replace all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find/replace a line break by deleting the (non-print) characters usually its CRLF (cartridge return + line feed) depending on the OS/program that created the file's content. Notepad++ will display non-print characters if you turn on "show all characters". To find that in notepad++ you can use `\r\n` (using extended search mode or regular expression).

In **scenario 1a** you should replace/delete all line breaks followed by a pipe (`\r\n|`):

- Find: `\r\n|`
- Replace with:   (leave empty)

This will change the following text:

```
dhdh
|jgfgf
hhgfh
```

to this text:

```
dhdhjgfgf
hhgfh
```

In **scenario 1b** you should replace all line breaks followed by a pipe (`\r\n|`) with a pipe (`|`):

- Find: `\r\n|`
- Replace with: `|`

This will change the following text:

```
dhdh
|jgfgf
hhgfh
```

to this text:

```
dhdh|jgfgf
hhgfh
```

In **scenario 2a** (from your question) you should replace/delete all line breaks (`\r\n`):

- Find: `\r\n`
- Replace with:   (one space character)

This will change the following text:

```
dhdh
|jgfgf
hhgfh
```

to this text:

```
dhdh| jgfgf hhgfh
```

In **scenario 2b** (from your comments) you should replace/delete all line breaks (`\r\n`):

- Find: `\r\n`
- Replace with:   (leave empty)

This will change the following text:

```
dhdh
|jgfgf
hhgfh
```

to this text:

```
dhdh|jgfgfhhgfh
```

**Note:**

Using RegEx instead of "Extended Search" you can use `\R` (note the upper case) instead of `\r\n` (see full [RegEx-Guide](https://letconex.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in.html)), thanks to [Toto](https://superuser.com/users/763386/toto) for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=\|)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?=\|)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have a pipe after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: good answer, two comments: `\r` only replaces RF not LF! Although `warp around` is helpful it's not necessary (without warp around the search will stop at the end of the text file, with it will continue at the beginning).

Comment: @Albin: I used `\R` (uppercase), it stands for any kind of linebreak as I said in my explanation. I use to always use wrap around because it makes the change global evan if your cursor is in the middle of the file.

Comment: nice, didn't know about the uppercase option, that's helpful, thanks!